# C++ private array element removed when trying to print in another function

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, int

I am sorry for the title, I don't know how to say this.

However, I have an int(GLuint but it is typically the same) array declared as private.

In a function, I add an element(in this case a texture) to the array and when I print it, it is fine.

But when I print the first element in another function(in that same class where the array is) it is gone and just 0(I think it is default 0 when you declare an integer array without elements in it)!

The array:

```
private:
    GLuint texture[20];
```

I am printing the first element(which I just added in that function), but in another function the element is just gone. I declared the array in a header file.

Is this enough or do I have to show more code(also OpenGL stuff)?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:

The function where the printing of the element is correct:

```
    void Window::initTextures(const char * imgPath, int index){
        //SDL TEXTURE TO CONVERT
        SDL_Surface * surface = IMG_Load(imgPath);

        //GENERATING THE TEXTURE
        glGenTextures(1, &texture[index]); //THIS STORES THE IMAGE IN THE ARRAY
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[index]);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        std::cout << texture[0] << std::endl; //THIS PRINTS THE ELEMENT

        //CHECKING IF RGB OR RGBA FORMAT
        if (surface->format->BytesPerPixel == 4) {
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, surface->format->BytesPerPixel, surface->w, surface->h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);
        }else {
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, surface->format->BytesPerPixel, surface->w, surface->h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);
        }

        //DESTROYING THE SURFACE(BECAUSE WE DONT NEED IT)
        SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
        test();
    }
```

**EDIT**:
This is the function where it just prints the default value of the array(0):

```
GLuint Window::getTexture(int index){
    std::cout << texture[0];
    return texture[index];
}
```

Comment: Can you show more code? Especially the print code that seems to make it disappear. (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AndyM I edited the question, I hope it helps

Comment: you probably made a copy of the `Window` class. Try to define a private copy-constructor and see if the compiler start complaining.

Comment: did you mean for `getTexture` to print `texture[0]` or `texture[index]`?

Comment: @Andy M It was actually meant to return the image for use in another class but I just used the function to find out what value the array element(0) had.

Comment: What calls `initTextures` and `getTexture`?

Comment: @immibis initTextures is being called by the window creating function(which executes only 1 times) and the getTexture function is called when I use the texture(first element in the array) in another class.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I defined a constructor in every class and passed the object to the class that calls initTextures. Now it works, thanks everyone! :D

Comment: So, when it was broken you had something like `Window w; w.getTextures()`, so you were getting the textures from a brand new `Window` that wasn't the one you loaded the textures into?

Comment: Yes, but I used different objects in multiple classes so they were copying not referencing. Btw I can not accept my own answer so this question keeps open :/